# Upper bound for a finite Euler product

Tags: analytic-number-theory

What is an upper bound for $$\left | \prod_{p}^{X}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{p^{\sigma + it}} \right )\right |$$ ($X>1$) for $0<\sigma<1$ in terms of $t$?

Comment: Assuming that the product is over all primes $p\le X$, the only uniform upper bound is the trivial $\prod_{p\le X} (1+1/p^{\sigma})$.   One can get arbitrarily close to this by using Kronecker's theorem to make $p^{it} \approx -1$ for all primes $p\le X$.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\left| \prod_{\substack{p \leq X\\ \text{prime}}} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^{\sigma+it}}\right)^{-1}\right|$ with the negative 1 power as it usually appears in the Euler product formula for the zeta function?